# How to train a Conditional Random Field/Markov Random Field Model for Object Classification in images given the features?

Tags: graphs, machine-learning, image-processing, computer-vision, classification

I want to classify superpixels in a image using a Markov Random Field/ Conditional Random Field model but have found no place that can help me with this (references don't even show how the network is visually). I already have the superpixels and the features associated to those superpixels, I'm only missing the MRF/CRF model.

Usually what i find is only for sequential data but this is more of a grid of nodes, and have found little to no code for the 2D case. Is there anything available for this sort of task? Or probably some guidelines of how can I program this given that I already have the features of each superpixels?